# How to enforce this one-to-many constraint in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have 2 classes: Box and Apple.

A Box contains Apples. An apple can only ever belong to one box. An apple must belong to a box.
Each apple has a position in the box. This could be managed either by Apple or by Box. An apple also contains a bunch of other properties not relevant to Box. An apple can be moved from one box to another.

But how can I enforce the constraints above?

The only idea I have is that a box keeps track of the position of an apple and also have a static dictionary mapping an apple to a board, but this seems like not good design?

Comment: classes are like blueprints. You cannot enforce the rules unless you use them. But you haven't mentioned how are you trying to use the classes and why you need to enforce the rules? The approach varies widely among uses. Try to provide more details, what you have tried so far, etc.

Comment: Can you show us code for your solution so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class ApplePosition, which contains Apple and position. Box will have list of ApplePosition

Comment: How can I prevent an apple from being added to multiple boxes though in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a third class, let's call it `AppleBoxer`. This class would be responsible for adding\removing\moving apples from boxes.

`AppleBoxer` would have a List of all `Box`, when you request to add an `Apple` to any given `Box` it will check if that apple is already in another `Box` before adding.

The free\occupied positions in the `Box` I would keep on the `Box` class.

I think the OOP principle here is the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

`Apple` is not responsible for knowing in which box it is in.

`Box` is not responsible for knowing about the apples of other boxes.

Comment: Although this is **the correct answer** from a perspective of design principles, it violates the question assumption "I have 2 classes: Box and Apple", that can be part of given constraints. At the moment, we do not know if OP is willing (or can) add other classes to the design. I totally support your solution, though, so: upvote :)

Comment: I think this is a good answer but what happens if someone does not use AppleBoxer? It seems like it would still be possible to add an apple to another box unless you make sure to always use appleboxer, and the same instance you used to box the apples.

Comment: You can use Dependency Inversion (DI) and pass `AppleBoxer` as a parameter to `Box`. Then on `Box.AddApple` you use the provided `AppleBoxer` to check if you can add the apple. You can make `AppleBoxer` a singleton to ensure only one instance.

Comment: If this is for an API you can also use private\internal to make sure developers can only access the right methods.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work for what seems like a common use case. In the real world, objects only exist in one place.

Comment: Well, it's some work, but good code pays off. I've implemented it if you want to take a look https://dotnetfiddle.net/DQSGXV

Comment: In Gabriel solution, neither `Apple` nor `Box` would expose anything that allow you to add an apple to a box without using an `AppleBoxer` class, that would contain logic to be sure every constraint is fulfilled.

Comment: @ClaudioValerio You could still do it in the same assembly as he is using internal.

Comment: One of my solutions has 49 projects, 81.000 classes, 730.000 lines of code ... tell me about "a lot of work"...

Comment: *"You could still do it in the same assembly as he is using internal"*: true, but from the design perspective is assumed that same assembly code knows what it is doing and how to use internal classes. @GabrielCappelli solution still seems solid, to me.

Comment: Actually, even with DI you could still do by just creating a new AppleBoxer yourself and passing it in to the constructor. With the singleton approach, it's just the same as using a static field like i proposed in the question. And internal is good for consumers but no good at documenting internal design by someone working on the project.

Comment: You can do a Singleton + pass it as a parameter instead of having it as a static... But at that point was the difference? Someone working on the same project can **always** break things. They can change existing code, or break design by adding public methods that expose things that were not supposed to be exposed, or a thousand other ways! The only way to prevent people with access to the code from breaking the design is to personally verify every single commit!

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: as stated by Gabriel C [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60446321/582792), ideal design would be one which respects the Single Responsability Principle. Your question though, if interpreted licterally, constraints to only 2 classes, which should contain all the business logic to handle apple boxing. Here my solution with this specific design.

**Apple class:**

```
public class Apple
{
    public enum AppleKind
    {
        RedDelicious,
        GrannySmith,
        Golden,
        PinkLady
    }

    public AppleKind Kind { get; }
    public Apple(AppleKind kind)
    {
        this.Kind = kind;
    }

    public Box Box { get; private set; }

    public void MoveToBox(Box box, int position)
    {
        if (box == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(box));
        int oldPosition = -1;
        var oldBox = this.Box;
        if (oldBox != null)
        {
            oldPosition = oldBox.GetApplePosition(this);
            oldBox.RemoveApple(this);
        }
        var moved = false;
        try
        {

            this.Box = box;
            Box.SetApplePosition(this, position);
            moved = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!moved)
            {
                if (oldBox != null)
                    oldBox.AddApple(this, oldPosition);
                else
                    this.Box = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void MoveToHand()
    {
        this.Box = null;
    }
}
```

**Box class:**

```
public class Box
{
    private Apple[] _apples;

    public IEnumerable<Apple> Apples
    {
        get
        {
            return _apples.Clone() as Apple[];
        }
    }

    public Box(int maxPositions)
    {
        _apples = new Apple[maxPositions];
    }

    public void RemoveApple(Apple apple)
    {
        var position = GetApplePosition(apple);
        if (position > -1)
        {
            _apples[position] = null;
            apple.MoveToHand();
        }
    }

    public int GetApplePosition(Apple apple)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(_apples, apple);
    }

    public void SetApplePosition(Apple apple, int position)
    {
        // if apple is already in position, do nothing
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(apple, _apples[position])) return;
        _apples[position] = apple;
    }

    public void AddApple(Apple apple, int position)
    {
        if (_apples[position] != null) throw new ArgumentException("Compartment already occupied", nameof(position));
        if (apple == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(apple));
        if (position < 0 || position > _apples.Length - 1) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Cannot add apple outside compartments");
        apple.MoveToBox(this, position);
    }
}
```

Please note that Box.Apples property returns a clone of the underlaying array, preventing client code from breaking Apple-Box relationship by manipulating array elements. Apple.Box has private setter for same reason.

Clone full code, including tests, at: https://github.com/cvalerio/TossAnAppleToYourWitcher

Comment: What is stopping someone from just creating a new apple and then calling SetApplePosition multiple times on the same box or on different boxes?

Comment: You may also add classes or break them apart as long as the constraint of an apple being bound to a box holds.

Comment: Well, if the constraints aren't bound by implementation, but can be logic, best solution is the one proposed by Gabriel C. As per the first comment: I opened an issue in repo (https://github.com/cvalerio/TossAnAppleToYourWitcher/issues/1), I'll leave it to you; github repo is public, fork it and propose pull request :) (aka: you don't want us to do all the work for you, do you?)

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple way is to create a AppleBoxManager class that contains a list of box instances and a dictionary to maps apples in the box items with surrogate keys

The surrogate key is a composition of boxId+appleId, when you add an apple in the box adds the key to the dictionary, when you change the apple to another box, remove the key and add the new key, the key prevent duplicity. You should to manage the logic errors in add, remove or change apple to box methods. I supose that all box and apples have a unique id.

A similar approach can be applied in the box class with the positions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deal with this is to have the apple class have a reference to the box it belongs to. Should you need to get all the apples in a box all you need to do is get the id of the box and search all apples that have this id in its FK_BoxID reference.

Should an apple move to another box. All you have to do is update the FK_BoxID in the apple class to move it.

[See UML example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w66Ci.png)